# How to use Timeline to perform a void method every x seconds on JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

The problem:

I'm trying to use Timeline to call a void method action() every 0.5 seconds. I have researched how to do this and looked at similar questions on this site, but none are working out for me.

What I have tried #1:

```
Duration sec = Duration.ofSeconds((long) 0.5);
this.timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(sec, e -> {
    action();
}));
```

The error the above caused:
"The constructor KeyFrame(Duration, ( e) -> {}) is undefined".

What I have tried #2:

```
this.timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.ofSeconds((long) 0.5), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() 
        {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                action();
            }
            }));
```

The error the above caused: "The constructor KeyFrame(Duration, new EventHandler(){}) is undefined".

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this line:

```java
Duration sec = Duration.ofSeconds((long) 0.5);
```

***Note:** Casting `0.5` to a `long` will simply give you `0`.*

You are using the wrong `Duration` class. The above indicates you're using [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) when you need to be using [`javafx.util.Duration`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.base/javafx/util/Duration.html). Remove the import statement for the former and replace it with one for the latter. Then change the above line to:

```
Duration sec = Duration.seconds(0.5);
```

Notice the static method for the JavaFX `Duration` class is named `seconds`, not `ofSeconds`. Also, if you want the `Timeline` to repeatedly call your method every `0.5` seconds then you need to set its [cycle count](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Animation.html#cycleCountProperty) to [`Animation#INDEFINITE`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Animation.html#INDEFINITE).

Here's an example:

```java
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class App extends Application {

  private Label label;
  private int count;

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    label = new Label();

    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.5), e -> incrementLabel()));
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.playFromStart();

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(label), 500, 300));
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  private void incrementLabel() {
    label.setText(String.format("%,d", count++));
  }
}
```

***Note:** "Incrementing" the text of the `Label` could be done directly in the `EventHandler`, but I moved it to a `void` method to better fit your question.*